# JavaScript Regex: Escape the string "c++"?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I'm working on some regex for a input text field and have had some trouble escaping special characters such as "+" or "?".

I've used [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) questions for doing so and they work for a string such as **c+** but if I enter **c++** I get following error in the console `Invalid regular expression: /c++/: Nothing to repeat`

Here's the code:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   var val = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
    // from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
    //val.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

    //from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex
    val = val.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");

    var re = new RegExp(val, 'ig');
    console.log(re);
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/45voca39/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your code. As a string is immutable in JavaScript, `replace` doesn't change it but returns a new one. You do the replacement but you doesn't take the returned value

Change

```
val.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
```

to

```
val = val.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8f3uryfd/)

Comment: Oh yes of cause, I feel so silly. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was fine, you just threw away the result of the replace call.
Replace with `val = val.replace(...);`

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45voca39/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much - it was so easy :-)